# How to ban password use on Ubuntu Hardy?

Tags: ubuntu

How to ban password use on Ubuntu Hardy?

I will be using Ubuntu instances on EC2 where passwords are not used but private keys are used to login via ssh.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the PasswordAuthentication line in /etc/ssh/sshd_config to no:

Old:

```
#PasswordAuthentication yes
```

New:

```
PasswordAuthentication no
```

And the restart sshd:

```
/etc/init.d/sshd restart
```

You should be good to go.

Comment: Oh, make sure you have the keys working *BEFORE* you make this change :)

Comment: Well I have modified the file. But cant restart sshd, I am getting error 'restart: command not found'.

Another thing is there is no file called sshd in location/etc/init.d/. There is a file called ssh.

So what do I do next?

Comment: well, i have finally worked out how to retstart ssh but the system is still promting to enter a password if run command passwd. Doesnt seems like it has been fixed properly.

Comment: Passwd is used to change the current password. It has no effect on if you may log in with the password or not. If you don't want a password promt there you have to run passwd as superuser. sudo passwd. You can setup sudo not to use password, using the sudoers file.

Comment: Yeah, it's /etc/init.d/ssh I'm used to RHEL systems, sorry :)